# How to share VPC Virtual Machines between Windows 7 and another OS?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am running Windows 7 RC with the new Virtual PC Beta for Windows 7.  I created a new XP VM from scratch (since the XP Mode one uses a differencing drive image).  When I shared it with a co-worker running Windows 2008 server it crashed VPC 2007.

Has anyone else attempted to share a VM between Windows 7 and another OS?  Is there a way to make them compatible?

If not, I know that Virtual PC 2007 ran fine in Windows 7 Beta.  Has anyone had any luck running the old Virtual PC 2007 in Windows 7 RC?  It currently reports it as incompatible and blocks the install, but that doesn't mean there isn't a work around.

**NOTE**: I am specifically looking for a way to be compatible between VPC 2007 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a different VM system, for example [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

Comment: Yeah. Then you can mount the same virtual drives on the two OSs and have the same virtual machine.

Comment: You are correct, that would work, but unfortunately my boss standardized on VPC 2007.

Comment: They're both free, and there are conversion utilties for both.  Would your boss get ticked if you went with VirtualBox?

Comment: I could go Virtual Box, but then I can't really share with the people who are using VPC 2007 then can I?

Comment: I've successfully used VPC virtual drives in Virtual Box. I haven't tried re-opening them in VPC afterwards through, so don't know if using them in VBox stops them from being usable in VPC.